# Python Dataframe Updating Flags

Tags: python

I am creating four columns which are labeled as flagMin, flagMax, flagLow, flagUp. I am updating these dataframe columns each time it runs through the loop whoever my original data is being override. I would like to keep the previous data I had in the 4 columns since they contain 1s when true.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('help test 1.xlsx')

#groupby function separates the different Name parameters within the Name column and performing functions like finding the lowest of the "minimum" and "lower" columns and highest of the "maximum" and "upper" columns.

flagMin = df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False)['Min'].min()
flagMax = df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False)['Max'].max()
flagLow = df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False)['Lower'].min()
flagUp = df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False)['Upper'].max()
print(flagMin)
print(flagMax)
print(flagLow)
print(flagUp)

num = len(flagMin)  #size of 2, works for all flags in this case

for i in range(num):
    #iterating through each row of parameters and column number 1(min,max,lower,upper column) 
    colMin = flagMin.iloc[i, 1]
    colMax = flagMax.iloc[i, 1]
    colLow = flagLow.iloc[i, 1]
    colUp = flagUp.iloc[i, 1]

    #setting flags if any column's parameter matches the flag dataframe's parameter, sets a 1 if true, sets a 0 if false
    df['flagMin'] = np.where(df['Min'] == colMin, '1', '0') 
    df['flagMax'] = np.where(df['Max'] == colMax, '1', '0')
    df['flagLow'] = np.where(df['Lower'] == colLow, '1', '0')
    df['flagUp'] = np.where(df['Upper'] == colUp, '1', '0')
    print(df)

4 Dataframes for each flag printed above
    Name       Min
0     Vo       12.8
1     Vi      -51.3

    Name       Max
0     Vo       39.9
1     Vi      -25.7

    Name       Low
0     Vo      -46.0
1     Vi      -66.1

   Name        Up
0     Vo       94.3
1     Vi      -14.1
```

Output 1st iteration

```py
      flagMax    flagLow   flagUp  
0        0         0         0  
1        0         0         0  
2        0         0         0  
3        1         0         0  
4        0         0         0  
5        0         0         0  
6        0         0         1  
7        0         1         0  
8        0         0         0  
9        0         0         0  
10       0         0         0  
11       0         0         0  
12       0         0         0  
13       0         0         0  
14       0         0         0  
15       0         0         0  
16       0         0         0  
17       0         0         0
```

Output 2nd Iteration

```py
      flagMax   flagLow   flagUp
0        0         0         0  
1        0         0         0  
2        0         0         0  
3        0         0         0  
4        0         0         0  
5        0         0         0  
6        0         0         0  
7        0         0         0  
8        0         0         0  
9        1         0         1  
10       0         0         0  
11       0         0         0  
12       0         0         0  
13       0         0         0  
14       0         0         0  
15       0         1         0  
16       0         0         0  
17       0         0         0
```

I lose the 1s from row 3,6,7. I would like to keep the 1s from both sets of data. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set to `'1'` only those elements you want to update and not the whole column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('help test 1.xlsx')

#groupby function separates the different Name parameters within the Name column and performing functions like finding the lowest of the "minimum" and "lower" columns and highest of the "maximum" and "upper" columns.

flagMin = df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False)['Min'].min()
flagMax = df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False)['Max'].max()
flagLow = df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False)['Lower'].min()
flagUp = df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False)['Upper'].max()
print(flagMin)
print(flagMax)
print(flagLow)
print(flagUp)

num = len(flagMin)  #size of 2, works for all flags in this case

df['flagMin'] = '0'
df['flagMax'] = '0'
df['flagLow'] = '0'
df['flagUp'] = '0'

for i in range(num):
    #iterating through each row of parameters and column number 1(min,max,lower,upper column) 
    colMin = flagMin.iloc[i, 1]
    colMax = flagMax.iloc[i, 1]
    colLow = flagLow.iloc[i, 1]
    colUp = flagUp.iloc[i, 1]

    #setting flags if any column's parameter matches the flag dataframe's parameter, sets a 1 if true, sets a 0 if false
    df['flagMin'][df['Min'] == colMin] = '1'
    df['flagMax'][df['Max'] == colMax] = '1'
    df['flagLow'][df['Lower'] == colLow] = '1'
    df['flagUp'][df['Upper'] == colUp] = '1'
    print(df)
```

P.S. I don't know why you are using strings of `'0'` and `'1'` instead of just using `0` and `1` but that's up to you.

Comment: I'll change the strings to integers, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi CrafterKolyan, 

`df['flagMin'][df['Min'] == colMin] = '1' `

Looking at this code, It seems like the entire dataframe would be populated by a one if the condition is satisfied. Is it possible to populate up to a certain group of rows?

Comment: @harro you can use `df.loc[rows, 'flagMin']` instead of `df['flagMin']` and the same change in condition

Comment: Thank you @CrafterKoylan. One more question, can I have two or more boolean logic within this line of code? I would like to add another condition within this line:   df['flagMin'][df['Min'] == colMin] = '1'

Comment: Yes you can unite conditions with `|` as `or` or `&` as `and`. But don't forget to put braces as the priority of operations is tricky here. `(df['Min'] == colMin) & (df['Max'] == colMax)` as an example.